# How to perform an anti-join, or left outer join, (get all the rows in a dataset which are not in another based on multiple keys) in pandas

Tags: pandas, anti-join

I have two datasets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'label1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'label2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'value': [1,2,3,4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'label1': ['A', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'label'2': ['a', 'd', 'c','e'], 'value2': [10,12,23,14]})
```

I would like to perform an anti-join so that the resulting data frame contains the rows of df1 where the key [['label1', 'label2']] is not found in df2.

The resulting df should be:

```
label1     label2     value
A          b          2
B          c          3
C          d          4
```

In R using dplyr, the code would be:

```
df3 = anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("label1", "label2"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `isin` with `tuple`

```
df1[~df1[['label1','label2']].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[['label1','label2']].apply(tuple,1))]
Out[140]: 
  label1 label2  value
1      A      b      2
2      B      c      3
3      C      d      4
```

Comment: This code did the trick..  My resulting data frame correct!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Option1**

Simply perform an inner join and remove the intersecting rows from `df1`.

```
df1.drop(df1.merge(df2).index)
```

**Option2:**

You need to do a left join and see how many of the rows shows up as null for the column from `df2`.

```
mer = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
mer[mer['value2'].isnull()].drop(['value2'], 1)
```

Output:

```
  label1    label2  value
1   A          b    2
2   B          c    3
3   C          d    4
```

Comment: Option 1 is great. - Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but when I apply the option 1 code to my larger dataset, it does not work.  I think the problem is that the merge creates a new index.  I end up with a dataset the correct size, but with the wrong rows.  I think the example here works because the only row to keep is the first.

Comment: @OliviaWatkins, do you get any error? In this case, option 2 would work.